# Winsock for Azure services

Tags: c++, windows, azure, iot, intel-galileo

I want to send sensor's data from intel Galileo running on windows to Azure. I tried the Casablanca sample and Azure storage SDK but they are giving many errors and it didn't worked for me. Is there is any other way to do that or please tell me the correct way to do that in detail as so far i have tried many things.

Is it possible to use [Winsock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to store data in Azure tables? Has anyone been able to run the Casablanca sample application, or use the C++ REST SDK with Galileo?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Azure Storage Client Library for C++ with Intel Galileo, but you have to do some modifications. You need to remove dependency on User32 library in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage project and also remove dependency to some other default libraries with this options:

-d2:-nolock /NODEFAULTLIB:ole32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:user32.lib

After that, if you have following error:

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _UnregisterClassW@8

you need to do a small workaround.

You need to define a dummy method UnregisterClassW in you version of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.v120 project
and you have to be sure that your version of Azure Storage Library is used by your Galileo application. Also, you need to take a right version of depending Casablanca project.

All modifications are described here:
http://kardum.net/iot/intel-galileo-windows-application-azure-storage/

I did similar example with Intel Galileo, so if you still have some issues, please let me know.

Best Regards,
Ivan

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to use Apache Qpid Proton library (Python, C, C++) to communicate through Azure Service Bus (Event Hubs or Topics/Subscriptions) by AMQPS 1.0.

After data passed Service Bus, you can use Azure Stream Analytics to take it from Event Hub, filter and put to storage or SQL Database/or create your own Worker Role.

Please, consult [Connect The Dots](http://connectthedots.io) project and my [pull requests](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/connectthedots/pulls/ivanignatiev).